# Kafka-python script does not execute properly

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I have run the below code in the Python Shell:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
future = producer.send('hello-topic', b'Hello, World!')
```

This works perfectly in that the Kafka consumer picks up the messages.

BUT...

Running it via a script does nothing.
Am I missing something obvious?

The only way to get it working as a script is to add this line...

```
future.get(timeout=10)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: add `producer.flush()` and you're good to go. so realistically, one is likely to have a loop and run `producer.send` many times. those messages may or may not be sent during the process but flush guarantees it. 

I guess `future.get()` also guarantees it but you're not gonna wanna use that for every send call.

Answer (score 0):

kafka send() details from the [link](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaProducer.html) : send() is asynchronous. When called it adds the record to a buffer of pending record sends and immediately returns. This allows the producer to batch together individual records for efficiency.
You can use flush()/poll() method to send the message immediately.